# Why are programmatically inserted SVG <tspan> elements not drawn, except with d3.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, d3.js, tspan

Say I want to programmatically insert an additional `<tspan>` in the `<text>` element in the following SVG:

```
<svg width="300" height="500">
    <text x="50" y="100">
        <tspan x="50">one</tspan>
        <tspan x="50" dy="20">two</tspan>
        <tspan x="50" dy="20">three</tspan>
    </text>
</svg>
```

This can be done with, among other things, pure JavaScript (`.appendChild`), jQuery (`.append`), and d3.js (`.append`).  However, although all three methods successfully insert the element, I can only seem to get it to *actually display* when it's inserted by d3.js:

See reduced case in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2NLJY/.

The behaviour is consistent across the browsers I've tested: Firefox, Chrome, and Safari (all OS X 10.8).

What is going on here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't use createElement to create SVG elements. SVG elements must be created in the SVG namespace so you need to write

```
document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "tspan");
```

There is a [jquery plugin](http://keith-wood.name/svg.html) which adds functionality to jquery allowing svg elements to be created.

Comment: That makes sense.  Fixing that has actually just led me back to the actual issue I was trying to investigate here: why are `dy` attributes being ignored (sometimes) when inserting `<tspan>` elements programmatically? http://jsfiddle.net/2NLJY/1/  This doesn't even look the same in Safari as it does in Chrome and Firefox...

Comment: @serhalp, that's another question. You should upvote and/or accept the answer above.

Comment: Though useful, it only partially answers my question.  Creating the element with createElementNS as stated does not display the `<tspan>` at the expected location.

Comment: Why did you change the setAttribute calls? They were correct. Don't use setAttributeNS for attributes other than xlink ones. Although elements are in the SVG namespace, attributes are usually not.

Comment: Thanks, that's it.  I think I've got some reading to do w/r/t namespaces.  One more thing: any idea why Safari ignores the `dy` attribute of a new `<tspan>` element inserted by d3, after having inserted one via `appendChild`? http://jsfiddle.net/2NLJY/5/